# Windows key don't work in windows 10

Tags: windows-10

My Windows Shortcut Button in windows 10 has been disabled for no reason and will not be fixed by restarting. I can not use combination keys right now.

Comment: Try to delete the keyboard in device manager, then reboot, and see if that works.

Comment: "Has been disabled". Using the registry or using Group Policy Editor it is possible to disable the Windows key. Are you in an organization? Are you the only user of that PC?

Comment: Have you tried a different keyboard, to rule out a faulty key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three ways you might have disabled your Windows key:

- Registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout`
  If this key exists, delete the item named `Scancode Map`
- Registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`
  If this key exists, delete the item `NoWinKeys`
- In the Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc), position to
  `User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\File Explorer`.
  Double-click "Turn off Windows Key hotkeys" and set it to "Not Conf‌igured"
  and click OK.

Reboot to test.

Create a System Restore save point before starting, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you have a button on your keyboard to disable the Windows key? My Zalman keyboard has a key to disable the Windows key. The image will probably be a Windows logo with a padlock icon.
2. Alternatively, use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ESC</kbd>

Comment: no i change my keyboard but problem exist,  i think problem is from windows

Comment: What about using CTRL+ESC?

Comment: What about the keyboard shortcuts which use Windows key?